# Can't Debug System Pref Pane under 10.15

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, macos-catalina

In Xcode 11.1, I have disabled SIP and set System Preferences as the debug executable. When I run my build, System Preferences loads, but when I open my prefPane, no breakpoints are ever hit.

This worked fine in 10.11 to 10.14.

With SIP enabled, I get a "can't attach to System Preferences" error as expected. But I am at a loss as to why the break points are never hit as they have been with earlier macOS versions.

I have a background process that is used by the prefPane and I am able to debug that just fine, but trying to debug the prefPane while it is running in System Preferences doesn't work anymore.

Has anyone got a solution?

Could this be because the prefPane is actually run in "legacyLoader" which is sub-launched by System Preferences?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to specify "legacyLoader" as the executable and not launch it automatically, but instead wait for it to be launched.

I still don't know how to do this without disabling SIP since there is no way to tell System Preferences to open an alternate (self-signed) copy of legacyLoader instead of the default system one.

Comment: I set Xcode to debug the legacyLoader, and it manages to attach (SIP is disabled), but breakpoints do not work... Any idea?

Comment: It worked for me to set Xcode (v11, macOS 10.15) to look for legacyLoader but you can't have it auto-launch. You have to tell Xcode you will launch legacyLoader manually which will happen when your prefPane loads. Since I wrote this, I have decided to move our product out of System Preferences into a stand-alone app. I never disabled SIP.

Comment: Yeah I got it working now. The reason why breakpoints did not work was because the binary got strippeed by accident. You really did not need to disable SIP?

Comment: `csrutil enable --without debug` relaxes SIP just enough to lift the task_for_pid restrictions.